# Linux Sed search special chars

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I'm looking to replace the value of a string in a file with `sed`.

Example with a file named `config.php` where I want to modify the value of john_doe which is 'other value' by '0.1.8' which contains:

```
$client_config['jane_doe'] ='value';
$client_config['john_doe'] = 'other value';
```

**But this command replaces the value of john AND jane doe which I obviously don't want. (There can be several spaces between the character =) :**

```
sed -i -e "/$client_config[\'john_doe\']*=/ s/= .*/= \'0.1.8\';/g" "/home/foo/config.php"
```

Comment: Why do you think your command will also replace `jane_doe`?  It won't. (You should properly escape the literal dollar sign, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work

```
sed -i -e "s/\(client_config.*john_doe.*\)'other value'/\1'0.1.8'/" your_file
```

Comment: Yes, it works with "sed -i -e ..." thanks a lot !